# C - Pthread goes into infinite loop unless I draw the image in between a given set of threads

Tags: c, pthreads

```
void    put_mandelbrot(int x_left, int x_right, int y_top, int y_bot)
{
    pthread_t   workers[10];
    t_param     inputs[10];
    int         i;
    int         x;
    int         y;

    i = -1;
    y = y_top - 1;
    while (++y < y_bot)
    {
        x = x_left - 1;
        while (x < x_right)
        {
            if (++i < 10)
            {
                inputs[i] = (t_param){++x, y};
                pthread_create(&workers[i], 0, (void *(*)(void *))mandelbrot_thread, (void *)&inputs[i]);
            }
            else
                while (--i > -1)
                    pthread_join(workers[i], 0);
        }
        while (--i > -1)
            pthread_join(workers[i], 0);
        // calling draw_image() here will get the correct result, drawn line by line
    }
    // if I don't call draw_image() above and for example want to draw
    // the whole image here after all of the lines are iterated
    // the program will become unresponsive
}
```

If I have the "draw_image()" function call in between each line, I get the image line by line and the program finishes it (I have checked this). On the other hand, if I only call the "draw image()" function after all of the iterations for all points (x, y) have been completed, the program never draws a single pixel and is unresponsive.

The "mandelbrot_thread" function simply iterates over a pixel (x, y) and sets the color of the pixel to a global image buffer which is always drawn in its entirety with the "draw_image()" call.

Why is this? I can't draw the image after every line as that makes the program insanely slow and makes no sense anyway. At the moment it seems to me that pthreads is working only when I'm actively checking it, almost as if to hide from any debugging attempts.

(edit: my mac also makes a very disturbing sound when I run this program, so there must be something very wrong with this)

Comment: A thread for each pixel is a lot of overhead.  Why not a thread for each line or for a group of lines?

Comment: Not sure if that has something to do with it, but it looks to me like `i` can be `-1` when dropping out of the first inner `while`. If that happens, the following `while` will put it at `-2`, which may become a problem for the next iteration.

Comment: `i` can't go below `-1` since `x` is only incremented inside the first `if` statement and in those cases `i` will always be above `-1`

Comment: @lkallio He's right, if `i` is -1 after the `while (x < x_right)` loop exits, the `while` right after that will decrement it to -2.  Better to put the decrement inside the loop.

Comment: @dbush yes it is a lot of overhead but does it explain this behavior?

Comment: @lkallio Probably not, but start with fixing the problem with `i` becoming -2 and then see where you're at.

Comment: It should not be necessary to cast the function pointer for the thread entry function.  If your compiler otherwise complains about mismatched types, then fix the function signature.

Comment: Although `0` is a valid null pointer constant, using it as one is usually confusing.  Prefer the macro `NULL` for that purpose.

Comment: The behavior you describe might be explained by `y_bot` being much larger than `y_top`.  We can't really tell from what you've given us, though.  Generally speaking, we need a [mre] in order to help with debugging.

Comment: @dbush `i` won't get to -2 since the condition that ends the loop is dependent on `x` and it is only incremented in the first `if` statement which also increments `i` - so `i` will always be at least 0 if the loop is to end. It's a bit difficult to see though, perhaps I should simplify the code I post here

Comment: @JohnBollinger it is necessary to cast the function pointer, as the thread function I am using is a void return function as opposed to the void * return function that is intended there.

Comment: @lkallio if `x_right - x` is a multiple of 10, `i` will be -1 when the loop exits.  Just take `--i` out of the condition and put it inside the loop and it won't be a problem.

Comment: @lkallio The function cast *is* a problem.  You need to change `mandelbrot_thread` to return `void *`, even if it always returns NULL.

Comment: You are missing the point, @lkallio.  If the system calls your function as if it is of one type when it really is of another type then undefined behavior results.  Casting only silences the compiler warning -- it does not make it ok to pass a pointer to a wrong-type thread-entry function.  You should fix the function instead of casting.  If indeed it presently returns `void` instead of `void *` then that shouldn't be too hard.